# how to use $this inside a function that is inside a method?

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

I have a function that is inside a class method.

In the method I can refer to `$this` but I cannot in the function. It will return this error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in
>   object context in
>   /var/www/john/app/views/users/view.ctp
>   on line 78

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
class View
{
    var $property = 5;

    function container()
    {
        echo $this->property;

        function inner()
        {
            echo "<br/>Hello<br/>";

            echo $this->property;
        }

        inner();
    }

}

$v = new View();
$v->container();
```

You can test it here [pastie](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NM5bTM)

**Is there a work around to make this work?**
I know I can pass $this in as a parameter, but is there any other way? Using `global $this` gives an error also.

*If your curious why I need this, its because my method is a view in an MVC model (or so it seems - I am using Cake), and in the view I need to use a function, and in the function I need to refer to `$this`.*

Comment: Is CakePHP still PHP4? If you can, use PHP5 class syntax.

Comment: @Felix, I am not sure what you mean. I am using PHP5. Can you give an example?

Comment: In PHP4 there was no way to specify the visibility of properties, but in PHP5 you can. E.g. you should define `$property` as `private`: `private $property = 5;`. More information here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: @felix, ooh OK I gotcha, this was just a quick example I do add access modifiers in practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do not make a function within another function, try this:

```
class View {
    var $property = 5;

    function container() {
        echo $this->property;

        $this->inner();
    }

    function inner() {
        echo "<br/>Hello<br/>";

        echo $this->property;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, as far as I know I cannot do that, I have to follow the framework. The entire view seems to be a method, and I need to call a function several times. Maybe views should not have functions - and I need to always create helpers instead?

Comment: I will rethink this and go another route. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

why not pass it with a parameter?

```
    function inner($instance)
    {
        echo "<br/>Hello<br/>";

        echo $instance->property;
    }

    inner($this);
```

Comment: I thought of this, but the function is a call back to something else, so its getting called indirectly. I guess maybe I can rewrite the other class that calls the callback to pass a reference though.

Comment: @John also anything that is passed wont have access to any private or protected vars

Comment: @Neal, thanks... Yeah I think I just need to rethink this one.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot yet comment, so I'm posting this answer instead.

This question seems CakePHP related to me, and I think you're overdoing the [View](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1079/View-Templates). As an example consider reading [Post Views](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1536/Creating-Post-Views) from the [CakePHP Blog Example](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog)

To sum up: if you are inside a CakePHP View, then you just output HTML with embedded PHP. The View has access to variables that you have `set` in the Controller action (i.e. `UserProfiles::index`). What I'd suggest is using something like the following:

```
<h2>UserProfile for <?php echo $user->name; ?></h2>
<?php if( $user->isAdmin() ): ?>
<p>You're an admin</p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>You're just a user</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also I'd suggest looking at [Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements), you can include them conditionally if required conditions are met ;).

Answer (score 0):

When PHP comes across a function definition, it defines the function into the global scope. So although you declare your function within a method, the scope of the function is actually global. Therefore the only way to access `$this` from within `inner()` would be to pass it as a parameter. And even then it would behave slightly differently than `$this` because you wouldn't be within the scope of the object.